# How to use joins and sum() in SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables `Items` and `Transactions`. In the items table, all the items are listed. In the transactions table it is where a particular employee can request for an item depending on the quantity that he/she requested.

How to use joins to merge the data from two tables that will compute for the balance quantity of each item?

Note: (Quantity Balance = Quantity - TR_Qty)

`ITEMS` table:

```
  | ID |  ITEM   | UNIT | QUANTITY | PRICE  |
  | 1  | Perfume | btl. |   50     | 200.00 |
  | 2  | Battery | pc.  |  100     | 25.00  |
  | 3  | Milk    | can  |  250     | 70.00  |
  | 4  | Soap    | pack |  400     | 150.00 |
```

`TRANSACTIONS` table:

```
  | ID | ITEM_ID | TR_QTY   |  REQUSETOR  | PROCESSOR   |   Date     |Time |     
  | 1  |   1     |    20    | A. Jordan   | K. Koslav   | 12-22-2014 |09:00| 
  | 2  |   2     |     8    | B. Wilkins  | Z. Flores   | 12-22-2014 |10:03|
  | 3  |   3     |    80    | C. Potran   | A. Mabag    | 12-26-2014 |14:23|
  | 4  |   3     |    45    | D. Korvak   | D. Sanchez  | 12-28-2014 |15:33|
  | 5  |   4     |    22    | C. Carvicci | A. Flux     | 12-31-2014 |16:02|
  | 6  |   1     |    18    | F. Sansi    | N. Mahone   | 01-22-2015 |08:45|
  | 7  |   4     |    14    | Z. Gorai    | M. Sucre    | 01-30-2015 |16:33|
  | 8  |   2     |     7    | L. ZOnsey   | P. Panchito | 02-11-2015 |17:22|
```

Desired output:

```
  | ID | ITEM    | QUANITY BALANCE|
  | 1  | Perfume |     462        |
  | 2  | Battery |     85         |
  | 3  | Milk    |     125        |
  | 4  |Soap     |     364        |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Items TABLE(ID INT, Item NVARCHAR(10), Q INT)
DECLARE @Transactions TABLE(ID INT, ItemID INT, TQ INT)

INSERT INTO @Items VALUES
(1, 'Perfume', 500),
(2, 'Battery', 100),
(3, 'Milk', 250),
(4, 'Soap', 400)


INSERT INTO @Transactions VALUES
(1, 1, 20),
(2, 2, 8),
(3, 3, 80),
(4, 3, 45),
(5, 4, 22),
(6, 1, 18),
(7, 4, 14),
(8, 2, 7)


SELECT i.ID, i.Item, MAX(i.Q) - ISNULL(SUM(t.TQ), 0) AS Balance 
FROM @Items i
LEFT JOIN @Transactions t ON t.ItemID = i.ID
GROUP BY i.ID, i.Item
ORDER BY i.ID
```

Output:

```
ID  Item    Balance
1   Perfume 462
2   Battery 85
3   Milk    125
4   Soap    364
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ITEM , ( SELECT (SUM(TRANSACTIONS.TR_QTY)-ITEMS.TR_QTY) FROM TRANSACTIONS WHERE TRANSACTIONS.ITEM_ID = ITEMS.ID ) AS QUANITY BALANCE FROM ITEMS
```

Field name and table name is as you mentioned in query ( you should change that as space is not valid for field or table name )

Comment: I'm sure this is not a valid t-sql because `quantity balance` won't be parsed as an identifier if it's written like that. I mean there is a space in the middle!

Comment: Yes , thatsy i metioned     " Field name and table name is as you mentioned in query "  , you can change the field name :)

Comment: What I mean is that there is little point giving an example that would never work. You could change it so that it has at least a half chance being valid t-sql

Answer (score 0):

You can do it for example by using outer apply and creating the sum of quantities in there:

```
select 
    I.ID,
    I.ITEM,
    I.QUANTITY - isnull(T.QUANTITY, 0) as BALANCE
from
    ITEMS I
    outer apply (
        select sum(TR_QTY) as QUANTITY
        from TRANSACTIONS T
        where T.ITEM_ID = I.ID
    ) T
```